# How to use flex grow with an overflow:scroll; item?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have an input area with variable height (up to a max-height of 120px). Above it will be a list of chat messages. With my example below, the input area expands in height but **overlaps** the list of messages as it grows.

I would like the container `.messages` to shrink in height as this happens, and ideally preserve its scroll position at the bottom of the container to see the last message posted.

```css
ul,
li {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100vh;
    flex: 1;
}

.messages {
  overflow: scroll;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.input {
  overflow: scroll;
  max-height: 120px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #efefef;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
    <ul class='messages'>
        <li>Message 1</li>
        <li>Message 2</li>
        <li>Message 3</li>
        <li>Message 4</li>
        <li>Message 5</li>
        <li>Message 6</li>
        <li>Message 7</li>
        <li>Message 8</li>
        <li>Message 9</li>
        <li>Message 10</li>
        <li>Message 11</li>
        <li>Message 12</li>
        <li>Message 13</li>
        <li>Message 14</li>
        <li>Message 15</li>
        <li>Message 16</li>
        <li>Message 17</li>
        <li>Message 18</li>
        <li>Message 19</li>
        <li>Message 20</li>
        <li>Message 22</li>
        <li>Message 23</li>
        <li>Message 24</li>
    </ul>
        <div class='input' contenteditable>
           
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add some JavaScript to your application. I have changed your class `messages` for an id instead (same should apply to your input window), since you only have one window for each.

```html
<div id="input" oninput="ScrollToBottom();"> </div>
```

```js
function ScrollToBottom() {
var objDiv = document.getElementById("messages");
    objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
}

/* You might want to call the function once your page loads as well 
   simply by adding this */
ScrollToBottom();
```

**See code snippet below for an example:**

```js
function test() {
  var objDiv = document.getElementById("messages");
  objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
}
 
/* call the function one time as well for when the window loads */
test();
```

```css
ul,
li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  flex: 1;
}

#messages {
  overflow: scroll;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.input {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  max-height: 120px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #efefef;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <ul id='messages'>
    <li>Message 1</li>
    <li>Message 2</li>
    <li>Message 3</li>
    <li>Message 4</li>
    <li>Message 5</li>
    <li>Message 6</li>
    <li>Message 7</li>
    <li>Message 8</li>
    <li>Message 9</li>
    <li>Message 10</li>
    <li>Message 11</li>
    <li>Message 12</li>
    <li>Message 13</li>
    <li>Message 14</li>
    <li>Message 15</li>
    <li>Message 16</li>
    <li>Message 17</li>
    <li>Message 18</li>
    <li>Message 19</li>
    <li>Message 20</li>
    <li>Message 22</li>
    <li>Message 23</li>
    <li>Message 24</li>
    <li>Message 25</li>
    <li>Message 26</li>
    <li>Message 27</li>
    <li>Message 28</li>
    <li>Message 29</li>
    <li>Message 30</li>
  </ul>
  <div class='input' oninput='test();'  contenteditable>
    User currently writing...
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm seeing the same behaviour in your example.. When I break a line in the input div it begins to overlap the messages (Message 30 will be covered in this example). I would like that not to happen as the user types..

Comment: Oh sorry, I missed that part of your question. You will need an EventListener in the javascript I think. I'll try to edit my question and answer properly.

Comment: @ogot Quick question : your goal is to limit the input's height to 120px also, yeah?

Comment: yes that's the idea, so it doesn't expand to fill the entire page. I thought flex box would take care of this kind of behaviour with flex-grow, but maybe I don't get how it is supposed to work.

Comment: @ogot I have edited my code snippet with an event listener `oninput`